# Files tries to upload agian after 1 minute timeout (DropZoneJS, FineUploader)

Tags: javascript, file, upload, dropzone.js, fine-uploader

We have a website with a drop zone for files upload
(using fine-uploader of course),

clients upload all kind of file sizes (1mb-5g),
when the upload is finished we don't send a response until we don't finish our  manipulation on the file which taking some time (depending on the file size, can take 5 minutes if the file size is 2g-3g).

Meantime the file is shown with the spinning wheel (waiting for response), and after 1 minute  the file is uploaded again (progress bar is resetting and new upload is starting ! and in the second upload after a 1/2 minutes approximately it get 504 gateway time-out).

And there is no new POST sent, but in the server I get another new file !

I will handle the 504, I think it is caused because of the nginx/gunicorn,
but why the libraries (dropzonejs, fine-uplodaer) can't wait 5 minutes for response, why they upload the file again. ?

Comment: It's not the libraries. It's the browser which "can't wait 5 minutes for response", 5 minutes is an eternity for an Ajax call to get a response. You need to re-design your system.

Comment: Have you tried substituting using `WebSocket` for `AJAX`?

Comment: I think gforce301 is right, we doing it wrong, We doing "wrong long-polling".